# pausar y cambiar de escena en unity

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy realizando un juego y tengo dos escenas. Una con el juego en sí y otra con los menus/submenus, que tienen incluso animaciones y efectos de partículas. 
El problema es que quiero ir a ese menú desde el juego pulsando escape y volver al juego donde se quedó. 
He probado con

```
Time.timeScale = 1f;
```

Pero eso me para todo, incluidas las animaciones del menú y claro, no me interesa.
He probado con Singleton

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {

            _instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);


            //Rest of your Awake code

        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
```

Acabé metiendo todos los elementos de mi juego en un GameObject y poniendo ese Script en el GameObject, me va al menú y cuando vuelvo empieza de nuevo. En el botón de Play del menú tengo esta línea:

```
 SceneManager.LoadScene("Stage_1");
```

Al menú principal voy apretando escape y con estas líneas:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("MenuScene");
```

Pero entonces lo que hace es superponer una escena sobre la otra y cuando vuelvo crea una nueva más la anterior...

Total, que no sé como hacer algo tan simple como pausar le juego, ir al menú y volver al juego tal cual...
Voy muy desencaminado? creo que estoy usando el el Singleton, que tiene buena pinta...¿se puede pausar una escena en concreto y no la otra? Porfi, alguna idea...

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, si usas Canvas puedes tener el menú flotando sobre la escena, incluso ponerle una imagen negra a pantalla completa que tape el "juego", y te ahorras el cambio de escena.

Y en cualquier caso, sobre la pausa en las animaciones, en el componente Animator tienes un campo UpdateMode que puedes poner en UnscaledTime, y así esas animaciones no se pausan con el `TimeScale = 0f;` es así cómo se hacen animaciones en los menús normalmente.

Yo creo que con esto puedes salir de tu lío, cualquier cosa avisa :P

Comment: Bueno, yo no soy un experto en esto asi que intentaré explicarte. El canvas de la escena del juego(Stage_1) es RenderMode=OverLay porque tiene los tipicos valores de vida y puntuación siempre presentes y el escenario del Menu(MenuScene) tiene el Canvas en RenderMode=Screen Space - Camera. porque quiero que haya un efecto de profundidad en los paneles con botones y además de las animaciones de los botones, tambien hay efectos de partículas en el background.  los efectos se detienen con el tiempo a 0f. y las luces de cada escena molestan a la otra. y no se como moverme con las camaras. :(

Comment: Tambien estoy partiéndome los cuernos con los de loadsceneAsync y UnloadSceneAsync pero lo único que estoy consiguiendo es un caos, o superpongo las dos escenas o cargo la del juego desde 0, ( yo quiero continuar donde lo dejé) y voy añadiendo escenas de juego una sobre otra, etc.

Comment: vale, ahora he conseguido que sobreviva el stage_1 con dontdestroyonload y puedo ponerlo en pausa para ir a la otra escena, porque los efectos de partículas tambien se pueden cambiar a UnscaledTime :(  . Ahora el problema es que cuando voy a la pantalla del menu desde el juego, la pantalla del juego se ve detrás y que cuando cargo de nuevo el escenario del juego, todos los objetos sobre el escenario se caen al suelo, pilares, cubos, etc... por alguna razón, supongo que porque crea otro suelo encima del viejo y luego destruyo el recién creado, bueno, estoy ahi ahi.